# How can I remove index in solr, on fields that marked as "indexed=true" in schema

Tags: solr

How can I remove index in SOLR, on fields that marked as `indexed=true` in schema
I have `solrschema.xml` which in past was modified by someone. So, now I have some fields marked with `indexed=true` but I do not want them indexed. Can I just make them `indexed=false` and then re-index my collection, if not, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward solution to remove a particular field from index.

- Here is some workaround if you don't have any space or resources limitations-

> Create index with new configuration and enable data import handler.

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

> Upload Data config file along with collection configuration files-

```
<dataConfig>
  <document>
    <entity name="sep" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="http://xyz:8983/solr/<old collection name>" query="*:*"/>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

> Run full refresh data import handler from solr admin UI.
>
> Once indexing is completed, delete old collection.

```
curl -i 'http://test:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETE&name=<old collection>'
```

> If you need new collection name same as old collection then create alias of new collection.

```
http://test:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=testalias&collections=anotherCollection,testCollection
```

For more details, browse [solr wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api4).